# Copying Column values in pandas to non zero cells and aggreagating columns after it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have  dataframe that looks like this

```
Index P1W1 P1W2 P1W3 P1W4 P2W1 P2W2 P2W3 P2W4 P3W1 P3W2 P3W3 P3W4
  0    A          B   C          A    D    D    A    
  1    B          A              C    C    B         A
  2               C   D
```

I want to convert it to

```
Index    P1         P2         P3
  0      A(P1W1)    A(P2W2)    A(P3W1)
  1      A(P1W3)    B(P2W4)    A(P3W2)
  2      B(P1W1)    C(P2W2)
  3      B(P1W3)    C(P2W3)
  4      C(P1W3)    D(P2W3)
  5      C(P1W4)    D(P2W4)
  6      D(P1W4)
```

Basically I want to get the column name with the cell value from first dataframe and then aggregate it at P1 P2 level.

If any clarification is needed please ask

I am completely clueless about how to go with this any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Setup**

```
txt = """\
Index P1W1 P1W2 P1W3 P1W4 P2W1 P2W2 P2W3 P2W4 P3W1 P3W2 P3W3 P3W4
  0    A          B   C          A    D    D    A    
  1    B          A              C    C    B         A
  2               C   D            """

df = pd.read_fwf(pd.io.common.StringIO(txt), index_col=0).fillna('')
df

      P1W1 P1W2 P1W3 P1W4 P2W1 P2W2 P2W3 P2W4 P3W1 P3W2 P3W3 P3W4
Index                                                            
0        A         B    C         A    D    D    A               
1        B         A              C    C    B         A          
2                  C    D
```

---

**Solution**

```
d = df + df.columns.map(lambda c: f'({c})')
pd.concat({
    g: d.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
    for g, d in d.where(df.astype(bool)).groupby(
        lambda col: col[:2], 1
    )
}, axis=1).fillna('')

        P1       P2       P3
0  A(P1W1)  A(P2W2)  A(P3W1)
1  B(P1W3)  D(P2W3)  A(P3W2)
2  C(P1W4)  D(P2W4)         
3  B(P1W1)  C(P2W2)         
4  A(P1W3)  C(P2W3)         
5  C(P1W3)  B(P2W4)         
6  D(P1W4)
```

---

**Details**

Add columns wrapped in parentheses

```
df + df.columns.map(lambda c: f'({c})')

          P1W1    P1W2     P1W3     P1W4    P2W1     P2W2     P2W3     P2W4     P3W1     P3W2    P3W3    P3W4
Index                                                                                                        
0      A(P1W1)  (P1W2)  B(P1W3)  C(P1W4)  (P2W1)  A(P2W2)  D(P2W3)  D(P2W4)  A(P3W1)   (P3W2)  (P3W3)  (P3W4)
1      B(P1W1)  (P1W2)  A(P1W3)   (P1W4)  (P2W1)  C(P2W2)  C(P2W3)  B(P2W4)   (P3W1)  A(P3W2)  (P3W3)  (P3W4)
2       (P1W1)  (P1W2)  C(P1W3)  D(P1W4)  (P2W1)   (P2W2)   (P2W3)   (P2W4)   (P3W1)   (P3W2)  (P3W3)  (P3W4)
```

Use a mask to make `NaN` at appropriate places.  This will enable us to stack within the comprehension and drop the `NaN` for convenience.

```
d = df + df.columns.map(lambda c: f'({c})')
d.where(df.astype(bool))

          P1W1 P1W2     P1W3     P1W4 P2W1     P2W2     P2W3     P2W4     P3W1     P3W2 P3W3 P3W4
Index                                                                                            
0      A(P1W1)  NaN  B(P1W3)  C(P1W4)  NaN  A(P2W2)  D(P2W3)  D(P2W4)  A(P3W1)      NaN  NaN  NaN
1      B(P1W1)  NaN  A(P1W3)      NaN  NaN  C(P2W2)  C(P2W3)  B(P2W4)      NaN  A(P3W2)  NaN  NaN
2          NaN  NaN  C(P1W3)  D(P1W4)  NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Group by a `lambda` which gets applied to the index object of our choosing.  We'll choose `axis=1` to target the columns.

Comment: That is clever !

Comment: The problem is that from P10W1 onwards all comes under P1.So is there any way that we can not mistake it P10 with P1

Comment: I sorted out that by considering 3 letters (P1W) instead of P1 and then renamed P1W to P1